# HMMT 1999 Calculus C8

Tags: probability, contest-math

A circle is randomly chosen in a circle of radius 1 in the sense that a point is randomly chosen
for its center, then a radius is chosen at random so that the new circle is contained in the original
circle. What is the probability that the new circle contains the center of the original circle?

I encountered some problems when reading the suggested solutions. 
https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/1999/feb/calc/solutions.pdf

In the solution, it let x be the distance between the center of the new circle and old circle and it seems to assume x follows a uniform distribution. Yet, I think that since the new centre is chosen uniformly in the circle, that the PDF of x should be 2x as the circumference of a circle grows linearly with its radius.

So ans is $  \int_0^{0.5} 2x\tfrac{1-2x}{1-x}\;\mathrm{d}x = \tfrac{3}{2}\; - 2\mathrm{log} 2$ and it differs from the answer in the solution. I would like to ask which part of it goes wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Whenever one speaks of choosing a point "randomly" inside a circle (or in more general contexts), care must be taken to specify the distribution.  I agree with you that I'd read the problem as requiring that the probability that the point lie in a subregion should depend only on the area of the subregion.  Of course there are other choices. Choosing the radius, and then the angle, uniformly gives different results.  See [Bertrand's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).

Comment: I agree with you also.  "Uniformly within the circle" without further qualification means proportional to the area, at least to me.

Comment: Yes, empiric test suggests your answer seems to be correct with my interpretation as well. I generated 1000000 circles by randomly choosing an x coordinate between -1 and 1, randomly choosing a y coordinate between -1 and 1, and trying again if the result isn't within the unit circle. I believe that should be uniformly distributed across the unit disk. Then I randomly chose a radius between 0 and $1 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. 113,578 of the million circles contained the origin, and $3/2 - 2\log(2) \approx 0.113706$.